# How to use a war file from Artifactory on a Dockerfile in a GitHub repository

Tags: docker, github, artifactory, dockerhub, jfrog-container-registry

I need help to build the CI pipeline to build only docker-image and push it to docker hub(all are private repository.

My requirement is: On the GitHub repository, I have a Docker file like the below:

```
FROM tomcat:alpine
COPY snoop.war /opt/tomcat/tomcat1/webapps/
EXPOSE 8443
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/cataline.bat run
```

In the above Dockerfile, instead of "snoop.war", I wanted to get the war file from the "jfrog" Artifactory location directly, since I cannot upload the war file into the GitHub repository due to security policies.

The expected Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM tomcat:alpine
COPY https://internal-jfrog-artifacts/war_file/mw_snapshots/snoop.war 
/opt/tomcat/tomcat1/webapps/
EXPOSE 8443
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/cataline.bat run
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the file first. Try build with below `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM tomcat:alpine
RUN apk add curl --no-cache \
    && mkdir -p /opt/tomcat/tomcat1/webapps \
    && curl -fsSL -o /opt/tomcat/tomcat1/webapps/snoop.war https://internal-jfrog-artifacts/war_file/mw_snapshots/snoop.war
EXPOSE 8443
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/cataline.bat run
```

Comment: `COPY` copies files from the docker build context to the image. If you run `curl` inside the image as above, the file is downloaded to the image filesystem, not to the build context. The `COPY` command will therefore fail (or worse... will not fail, copying a previous leftover version of the file in the build context). You would have to `RUN cp ...` or `RUN mv ...`  inside the image to copy/move the file to its final destination. But there is absolutely no need to do that: simply `curl` the file in place and you're done.=> `curl [...] -o /opt/tomcat/tomcat1/webapps/snoop.war [...]`.

Comment: @Zeitounator How about `RUN`  will ensure downloading the latest snoop.war everytime before baking that into image?

Comment: It will not ensure downloading every time by default as is: this layer will go in the build cache. And what is the relation with the `COPY` command that will fail anyway ? An example is better than yet-an-other-too-long-comment: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f1f009d89288185e211d60cf481f509f As you can see in the first run, your above example simply fails and you should fix it. Feel free to grab from mine in the second part of that gist if your feel like it. Cheers !